# Good ways to name django projects which contain only one app

Tags: python, django

When creating projects which contain just a single app, what are the good ways to name the project?

I can think without any confusion how to name my app but I need a project name for it. (Can i create a app without a project? If yes, Is it good to do that ?)

[Update] 
I saw some projects on github which contain single app are named as django-[appname].
I liked it and will be following it for naming my projects which contain a single app.
Django might be overkill for single app projects but as of now i have just started learning django so i have only one app in my projects.

Thanks

Comment: You have to create site/project and app in it, I don't think there is escape from it.

Comment: Note that apps that names themselves django-[appname] are generally reusable apps, they don't have their own django project. Don't use that naming convention if your app isn't a reusable app.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, for projects that are going to be used by only one installation, I usually name my projects as "who will be using the system" (e.g. the organization's name) and the apps as "major features of the system".

However, if your app is really that simple that you don't expect to be using multiple apps, then django might be too heavyweight and you might actually be better served by using something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to Django, but in what I've read of the documentation I haven't found any naming conventions for projects as they depend on too many factors. Instead, use general names for projects and more specific names for apps:

```
project = humanresource
apps = salaries, badge, whatelse...
```

Remember that projects come first, and apps can be reused in different projects.

Answer (score -1):

With django, you need a project - that is what holds the settings, urls modules. And a project needs a minimum of one app.

Most projects consist of a lot of apps. Organization is necessary and this is the preferred method. However, if it is a very simple app, for which you think all of this boilerplate is overkill and like to keep it in a single file, you can do so using some of the other micro frameworks like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: how does that answer the question? grass is green and sun is yellow, sometimes grass is not green, but most of the time is. sky is blue.